# Can I put a prop inside of v-for? Trying to work with vue/rest-api with a dynamic component

Tags: vue.js, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I am struggling to figure this out because I don't know how to ask the question. I am trying to create a dynamic component to pull in data from a wordpress rest api. I am pulling in the data dynamically, I am just having trouble getting my v-for loop to display. Here is the component code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li
                v-for="item in this.$props.cat" :key="item.id"
                :class="{highlight:selected.includes(item.id)}"
                @click="selected.includes(item.id) ? selected.splice(selected.indexOf(item.id), 1) : selected.push(item.id)"
            >
                {{ item.value }}
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  props: ['cat'],
  data() {
    return {
      category: [],
      selected: []
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://marygunnfunn.com/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options/`+this.$props.cat)
      this.category = res.data
      console.log(this.category)
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  },
}
</script>
<style lang="sass">
    .highlight 
        color: $red
        font-weight: bold
</style>
```

The data that I am pulling in looks like this:

```
{"colors":[{"value":"Bright"},{"value":"Neutrals Plus One"},{"value":"Cool"},{"value":"Pastel"},{"value":"Sunset"},{"value":"Bold like a 1st grader"},{"value":"Forest colors"},{"value":"Pinks and blacks"},{"value":"Sunny summer colors"},{"value":"Citrus"},{"value":"Winter"},{"value":"Fall"},{"value":"Red, White & Blue"},{"value":"Teals and oranges"},{"value":"Summer daisy garden"},{"value":"Bright Pinks plus 2"},{"value":"Coral and cool"},{"value":"Black, White, & one"},{"value":"Blues & two"},{"value":"Greens & two"},{"value":"Reds, Yellow, Blue"},{"value":"Purples\/pinks & two"},{"value":"Yellows & two"},{"value":"Monochromatic"}]}
```

The line in question is:

```
v-for="item in this.$props.cat" :key="item.id"
```

The reason I am trying to do this is because each set of data that I am pulling in has a different initial value in the object, so I need it to be dynamic. I can't figure out from the documentation if I am using ***this.$props.cat*** correctly inside of the v-for.

I don't know the terms well enough to figure out what I need to know, so any guidance is appreciated!!! I have been digging through vuejs and axios docs for a few hours and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: don't use `this` in the template, because its context is not the Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using `this.category` in your code.  Try changing the loop to the following:

```
<li
    v-for="item in category" :key="item.id"
    :class="{highlight:selected.includes(item.id)}"
    @click="selected.includes(item.id) ? selected.splice(selected.indexOf(item.id), 1) : selected.push(item.id)"
>
    {{ item.value }}
</li>
```

Note: you don't need to reference `this` inside a Vue template (the HTML part).  You also may want to change the variable name to `categories` to convey that it's an array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I don't think I asked the question the right way.  Is there any way to make `v-for="item in categories.colors" :key="item.id"` the .colors part dynamic?